ReactFlow is not persisting data using its own hooks and provider
So I have this app
<ErrorBoundary>
      <RFProvider>
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
          <ViewContainer>
            {flowView && (
              <SlideTransition direction="down" in={flowView}>
                <Container100>
                  <FlowView />
                </Container100>
              </SlideTransition>
            )}
            {mapView && (
              <SlideTransition direction="up" in={mapView}>
                <Container100>
                  <MapView />
                </Container100>
              </SlideTransition>
            )}
          </ViewContainer>
        </DndProvider>
      </RFProvider>
    </ErrorBoundary>

And the RFPRovider is basically a manually written provider (because reactflowprovider is not persisting data, more on this later)
THis is RFPRovider
export interface RFContextType {
  nodes: Node[];
  edges: Edge[];
  onConnect: (connection: Connection) => void;
  setNodes: (nodes: Node[]) => void;
  setEdges: (edges: Edge[]) => void;
  onNodesChange: OnNodesChange<Node>;
  onEdgesChange: OnEdgesChange<Edge>;
  handleNodeChange: (id: string, data: { url: string }) => void;
  onNodeClick: (_event: React.MouseEvent, node: Node) => void;
  onEdgeClick: (_event: React.MouseEvent, edge: Edge) => void;
  selectedNodeId: string | null;
  setSelectedNodeId: (id: string | null) => void;
  selectedEdgeId: string | null;
  setSelectedEdgeId: (id: string | null) => void;
}

export const RFContext = createContext<RFContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const RFProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const {
    nodes,
    setNodes,
    onNodesChange,
    selectedNodeId,
    setSelectedNodeId,
    handleNodeChange,
    onNodeClick,
  } = useNodeState();

  const {
    edges,
    setEdges,
    onEdgesChange,
    selectedEdgeId,
    setSelectedEdgeId,
    onConnect,
    onEdgeClick,
  } = useEdgeState();

  // Handle delete keypress
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === KEY_EVENTS.DELETE) {
        if (selectedNodeId) {
          setNodes((nds) =>
            nds.filter((node) => node.id !== selectedNodeId)
          );
          setEdges((eds) =>
            eds.filter(
              (edge) =>
                edge.source !== selectedNodeId && edge.target !== selectedNodeId
            )
          );
          setSelectedNodeId(null);
        } else if (selectedEdgeId) {
          setEdges((eds) => eds.filter((edge) => edge.id !== selectedEdgeId));
          setSelectedEdgeId(null);
        }
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [selectedNodeId, selectedEdgeId, setNodes, setEdges, setSelectedNodeId, setSelectedEdgeId]);

  return (
    <ReactFlowProvider>
      <RFContext.Provider
        value={{
          nodes,
          edges,
          onConnect,
          setNodes,
          setEdges,
          onNodesChange,
          onEdgesChange,
          handleNodeChange,
          onNodeClick,
          onEdgeClick,
          selectedNodeId,
          setSelectedNodeId,
          selectedEdgeId,
          setSelectedEdgeId,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </RFContext.Provider>
    </ReactFlowProvider>
  );
};

So now for example, if I am to open the FlowView, do some stuff there, setup some nodes and whatsover
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { Background, BackgroundVariant, MiniMap, ReactFlow } from '@xyflow/react';
import '@xyflow/react/dist/style.css';
import Sidebar from '../../components/reactflow/sidebar/Sidebar';
import useDragAndDrop from '../../components/hooks/reactflow/useDragAndDrop';
import { Container100 } from '../../styles/styled.global';
import { DropArea } from './styled';
import { GRID_TARGET } from './constants/constants';
import { createNodeTypes } from './helpers';
import { useRFContext } from '../../components/hooks/context/useRFContext';

const FlowView: React.FC = () => {

  const {
    nodes,
    setNodes,
    edges,
    onNodesChange,
    onEdgesChange,
    onConnect,
    handleNodeChange,
    onNodeClick,
    onEdgeClick,
    selectedNodeId,
    setSelectedNodeId,
    setSelectedEdgeId
  } = useRFContext();

  const { dropRef, isOver } = useDragAndDrop(setNodes, setSelectedNodeId);
  const nodeTypes = useMemo(() => createNodeTypes(selectedNodeId, handleNodeChange), [selectedNodeId, handleNodeChange]);

  return (
    <Container100>
      <Sidebar />
      <DropArea
        ref={dropRef}
        $isOver={isOver}
        onClick={(evt) => {
          if (evt.target instanceof HTMLElement && evt?.target?.classList?.contains(GRID_TARGET)) {
            setSelectedNodeId(null);
            setSelectedEdgeId(null);
          }
        }}
      >
        <ReactFlow
          nodes={nodes}
          edges={edges}
          nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
          onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
          onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
          onEdgeClick={onEdgeClick}
          onConnect={onConnect}
          onNodeClick={onNodeClick}
        >
          <MiniMap />
          <Background variant={BackgroundVariant.Dots} gap={12} size={1} />
        </ReactFlow>
      </DropArea>
    </Container100>
  );
}

export default FlowView;

and then after I want to read the nodes in MapView using the ReactFlowProvider , which is included in my RFProvider and wrapping the MapView. For that I have two options, one if using the REactFlowProvider provided by the package, and writting useNodes() , but in this case, I get 2 rerenders wit the appropiate data accesible, but suddenly it emptyies, and the array of nodes is empty. Meanwhile if I use the RFContext , I can access the nodes as expected, but I would rather use the provided hook
import React from 'react';
import { Map, NavigationControl, Popup } from 'react-map-gl/maplibre';
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css';
import { INITIAL_VIEW_STATE, MAP_STYLE } from './constants';
import { DeckGLOverlay, getPopupCoordinates } from './helpers';
import useGeoJsonLayers from '../../components/hooks/map/useGeoJsonLayers';

import { useRFContext } from '../../components/hooks/context/useRFContext';
import { useNodes } from '@xyflow/react';

const MapView: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    nodes,
    edges,
  } = useRFContext();

  const { layers, hovered } = useGeoJsonLayers(nodes, edges);

  console.log("Custom context")
  console.log(nodes)
  console.log("-----------------")


  const nodes2 = useNodes()
  console.log("useNodesHook")
  console.log(nodes2)
  console.log("----------------")

  return (
    <Map initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE} mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}>
      {hovered && (
        <Popup
          key={hovered.properties.name}
          anchor="bottom"
          style={{ zIndex: 10 }}
          longitude={getPopupCoordinates(hovered)?.[0]}
          latitude={getPopupCoordinates(hovered)?.[1]}
        >
          {hovered.properties.name} ({hovered.properties.abbrev})
        </Popup>
      )}
      <DeckGLOverlay layers={layers} />
      <NavigationControl position="top-left" />
    </Map>
  );
};

export default MapView;

useRFContext is basically my context
import { useContext } from "react";
import { RFContext, RFContextType } from "../../../context/react-flow/Context";

export const useRFContext = (): RFContextType => {
    const context = useContext(RFContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('No RFContext provided');
    }
    return context;
};

So why is it being reset
This is how the renders look

